# Python Selinium Javascript button download file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, headless

Website: https://myir.ird.govt.nz/eservices/home/?link=RWTEXREG

I'm attempting to download this file. It looks like the request is handled server side so there isn't any download link per se.

I've tried a bunch of things, including:

```
result = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'CaptionLinkText')]").text
```

But I really feel like I'm out of my element (no pun intended) with this.

Comment: If you're going to downvote a question, it would help to leave a comment so I can improve.

Comment: Maybe the downvote is due to not liking puns? I don't know, puns are fun!

Comment: @LeeJensen lol!

Answer (score 0):

Try `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()="Download"]')`

This says, "starting anywhere `//`, give me any element `*`, whose `[]`, text()="Download". Note that text is a function and not an attribute.

You can test the selector by opening [F12] DevTools going to the "Elements" tab, and doing ctrl+f to open the input to try things out.

I keep this handy for XPATH: https://devhints.io/xpath

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go tomorrow and if all is good I will mark it with the tick